# python 2.6 trivia game, true/false, multchoice, at random

Tags: python, random, python-2.6

```
import random

class Trivia(object):
    points = 0
    def __init__(self, mult_tf, question, options, correct, reason):
        self.mult_tf = mult_tf
        self.question = question
        self.options = options
        self.correct = correct
        self.reason = reason
        mult_tf, question, options, correct, reason = block

    def next_line(the_file):
        line = the_file.readline()
        line = line.replace('/', '\n')
        return line

    def questions(self, block):
        file_name = open('Trivia_Questions.txt', 'r')
        while True:
            mult_tf = next_line(file_name)
            question = next_line(file_name)
            options = []
            if mult_tf == 'Multiple Choice':
                for i in range(4):
                    options.append(next_line(file_name))
            else:
                for i in range(2):
                    options.append(next_line(file_name))
            correct = next_line(file_name)
            reason = next_line(file_name)
            mult_tf, question, options, correct, reason = block
        file_name.close()

    def rand_quest(self):
        for block in questions():
            questions.shuffle()
            return questions

    def show(self):
        while True:
            print mult_tf
            print question
            print options
            guess = raw_input('\nWhich do you choose? ')
            if guess == correct:
                print '\nCorrect!'
                points += 10
            else:
                print '\nIncorrect!'
            print reason
        print '\nYou completed the game!'
        print '\nYou got', points, 'points!'

Trivia.show()
raw_input('\n\nPress enter to exit')
```

I posted a question a few hours ago on the same question. I believe I have gotten a little further in my search for an answer. The code above is supposed to be on a trivia game with multiple choice and true/false questions. I believe I am close to the solution I just cannot get it to run properly.
I constantly get this error:

```
Trivia.show()
TypeError: unbound method show() must be called with Trivia instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Not quite sure what the arguement should be, I thought that the show method would print what I needed it to print.

Comment: You're consistently forgetting to refer to the instance variables. For example, `questions()` is an instance method, so it should be referring to `self.mult_tf` instead of `mult_tf`, `self.question` instead of `question`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`show()` is an *instance method*, so to call it you need to create an instance of the `Trivia` class, e.g.:

```
trivia = Trivia(mult_tf, question, options, correct, reason)
trivia.show()
```

---

More broadly, though, your class doesn't make any sense. A few examples:

`__init__` won't work, because in the last line:

```
mult_tf, question, options, correct, reason = block
```

which means "unpack the five items in `block` into these other five variables", the name `block` isn't defined, so you will get a `NameError`. Therefore you can never create a class instance and nothing else will run.

`next_line` seems fine, except you don't have a `self` argument, but it isn't really a class or instance method (it doesn't use any attributes of the class or instance) so probably doesn't belong in the class anyway.

`questions` is a bit odd; it gets all these values from the file, then the method ends without actually doing anything with them, having overwritten their values with whatever is in `block`. Nothing gets returned or added to the instance, so it may as well never have run.

`rand_quest` also has name errors, as `questions` isn't defined (nor is it an argument). You could *call `self.questions()`*, except that doesn't really do or return anything, as discussed. Functions don't have a `shuffle()` method unless you define it, and even if you got the syntax right (`random.shuffle(questions)`) you can't shuffle a function - what would that even mean?

In `show`, there is nothing to end the `while True` loop, so this would just run forever, except for the fact that you have a whole load of `NameError`s there too (e.g. `mult_tf` doesn't exist in that scope, although `self.mult_tf` *does*.

---

I think you need to split this into three things:

1. A `Trivia` class, where each instance is one question. This has an `__init__` method (takes the attributes, returns nothing), a `show` method (takes no arguments, returns a string) and a `check_answer` method (takes a string, returns a boolean).
2. An `import_file` function, which takes a filename and returns a list of `Trivia` instances based on the contents of the file.
3. A game loop, which gets the list of questions from `import_file` then `random.shuffle`s them and asks them.

Comment: Now im getting:

    trivia = Trivia(mult_tf, question, options, correct, reason)

    NameError: name 'mult_tf' is not defined

Comment: @AnthonyBarcume well, yes; you will have to actually define those variables to pass to the class to initialise the instance.

Comment: oh.. if I can figure out what that means then maybe I will fix this

Comment: @AnthonyBarcume I have added some comments. Your code at the moment is very confusing and doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Thank you man, ill go ahead and try to fix all these mistakes.